# Hide tag children when div exceed Multi Select width and show X selected in a tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Good morning everyone.

I need some help to go over the problem I am encountering.

I would like to know how would you guys do to resolve this problem.

I have a custom multi-select component and I can add selected elements from the options inside the multi-select to show which option is selected.

When I select an option it will be added as a tag to show the user which one was selected.

But when adding too many tags it will either go over the width or go into a new line inside the multi-select.

My question is, how would you show the x tag to be displayed but when the x tag is over the parent width it will instead show as the last tag X selected?

Thank you for your answer.

Have a good day!

I tried to have a limited tag number so that if there is more than the limited tag it will then display a new tag with X selected element. But I want to do it dynamically with width because, with a limited tag number, it can or can not go over the multi-select width (cf: if you got 3 tags but each of them doesn't have the same width)